# How to change color of path in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a device that gives to me the heart_rate in double. And I compute the result in a method that gives a color. For example if the heart_rate is between 20 and 47 returns green color, etc. What I meant was that if the value of heart_rate during that period was greater than 47, the stroke color would be red. But if the value was less than 47 heart_rate the stroke color would be green. Thus for example have a part of the path in red and the other green. With my implementation the stroke color is all changed and not broken into colors as I wanted.

My code:

```
//method that change the color of the stroke
public int mudaLinhaCor(String heart){

    Double valor = Double.parseDouble(heart);
    if(valor >=20 && valor <= 47){
        cor = Color.GREEN;
    }
    else if (valor > 47 && valor <= 60){
        cor = Color.GRAY;
    }
    else if (valor > 60 && valor <= 80){
        cor = Color.YELLOW;
    }
    else if (valor > 80 && valor <= 100){
        cor = Color.MAGENTA;
    }
    else if (valor > 100){
        cor = Color.RED;
    }
    else{
        cor = Color.BLACK;
    }
    return cor;
}


@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
    longi = String.valueOf(longitude);

    posCurrent = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); // a minha posicao corrente no mapa
    posAtuais.add(posCurrent);

    posInicial = posAtuais.get(0);
    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(posInicial));

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posCurrent, 16));

    //desenha o traco que mostra o caminho que o user ja percorreu
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(mudaLinhaCor(heart_rate)).geodesic(true);
    for (int z = 0; z < posAtuais.size(); z++) {
        LatLng point = posAtuais.get(z);
        options.add(point);
    }
    line = map.addPolyline(options);
```

Someone could help me.

Comment: Where do you get `heart_rate` which is used in method `onMyLocationChange()`?

Comment: From a service, and I show this value in a TextView.The value of heart_rate is correct. Each time the value changes, whole the stroke color also changes

Comment: It seems that in for loop you pick up all points up to the last one in update `options`. So color is the same for all of them. If you want different color than you will have to add new line for each different heart rate section.